# The best way for a WAR file to receive data from an external file

Tags: java, tomcat, war, configuration-files

I have a WAR file that requires additional data from an external config file residing in the same folder as the WAR file.

But once I deploy them to Tomcat, the WAR file and the config file will be residing in different places right?

Do I need to insert a special file path to my project before building the WAR file to make sure that the WAR file will still find the config file after deployment?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- include the config file inside the war and read it from this predefined location. This isn't good if you're going to change it after you deploy since every time you deploy a new war, your changes will be overwritten
- put the config file outside the war (and maybe even outside of tomcat) and read it from there. Doing this, your changes will survive redeploys of the war.

Comment: Thanks.  But in this case, if I put the config outside the war, is there a permanent filepath that the war can always find after deployment?

Comment: Sure. you can use any path you want and you just make sure that path (and file) exists when you deploy it.